# What is the max length of tag string in NebulaGraph Database?

Tags: nebula-graph

The `Tag` name in Nebula Graph is a string. what is the max length of this `Tag` name?

For example:

```
CREATE TAG IF NOT EXISTS aveeeeeeerylooooooooongtaaaaaaaagnaaaaaame(name string, age int);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct restriction on a string's length. But a sentence's length has an upper limit of 4MB.

I.e., The length of any queries or sentences you sent to Nebula Graph should be less than 4MB.